# Cannot find /bin/avr-g++

Tags: arduino

I am trying to compile a program with the Arduino IDE but can't because suddenly it returns these errors

```
Arduino: 1.6.5 (Linux), Board: "Arduino/Genuino Uno"

Cannot run program "{runtime.tools.avr-gcc.path}/bin/avr-g++" (in directory "."): error=2, No such file or directory

  This report would have more information with
  "Show verbose output during compilation"
  enabled in File > Preferences.
```

When I do a locate

```
[tom@ArchBak ~]$ locate -i avr-g++
/usr/bin/avr-g++
/usr/share/arduino/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avr-g++
/usr/share/man/man1/avr-g++.1.gz
```

Anyone has any idea?

Comment: What is `{runtime.tools.avr-gcc.path}`?